# Variavél de ambiente do no Windows auto increment

Tags: java, windows, applet, variáveis-de-ambiente

### Pergunta resumida

Preciso de de uma variavél de ambiente no windows que seja auto increment:

> setx /a PORT=1000

e toda vez que chamar a %PORT%:

> setx /a PORT=%PORT% + 1

o resultado seria:

```
echo %PORT%
1001
echo %PORT%
1002
echo %PORT%
1003
```

o que leva a pergunta,

Onde colocar o comando ?

> setx /a PORT=%PORT% + 1

---

### Pergunta explicada

Estou tentando debugar um applet em java no windows, 
outras configurações não funcionaram, a única  que funcionou
foi

criar uma variavél de ambiante

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=2502
```

Só que ao fazer isso somente 1 aplicação java pode ser excutada, ao tentar executar uma segunda um erro é lançado dizendo que a porta `2502` já está em uso.

minha idéia agora é fazer algo como

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=%PORT%
```

no qual `%PORT%`  vai ser um número incrementado.

Comment: Para criar uma variável de ambiente o comando não é [setx](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc755104%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?

Comment: obrigado pela correção

Comment: Acho que seria bom criar uma bat, que incrementasse `%PORT%` e depois chamasse o applet, se não me engano seria `call c:\applet.java`

Comment: o applet já é chamando por uma aplicação java web, não tem como mudar isso